# What does x* mean in the integral definition?

Tags: limits, definite-integrals

I was looking for the sum definition of limit and came across this diagram, but I don't know what the x*I means. I know it's different from x though. Thanks in advance!

[image]

Comment: $x_i^*$ is any point in the $i$'th interval.

Comment: So what would f(x*i) be if f(x) = x^2?

Comment: If $f(x)=x^2$, then $f(x_i^*)=(x_i^*)^2$.

Comment: $x_k^*=a+k \Delta x=a+k\frac{b-a}n$

Answer (score 2):

This is a Riemann sum. Say we want to integrate on an interval $[a,b]$. To approximate this, we partition $[a,b]$ into $n$ subintervals whose endpoints are given by $x_0=a, x_1, x_2, ..., x_n = b$ where $x_0 < x_1 < x_2 < ... < x_n$. Then, for each $i < n$, we arbitrarily choose some $x_i^* \in [x_{i-1}, x_i]$. $f(x_i^*)$ is, in a sense, an estimate as to "how big" $f$ is on the interval $[x_{i-1},x_{i}]$. Then the Riemann sum is given by the formula in your image. The integral is then defined as the limit (if it exists) of the Riemann sums as the largest interval gets smaller and smaller.